# What's the meaning the regex [^\p{LD}\s]?

Tags: java, regex

Could you please explain me what is the meaning of the following regex: `[^\\p{LD}\\s]`. I know that `^` means negation, `\s` means white spaces, but I can't gather it all together, especially this part with `{LD}`. Could you please help?

It's a part of the following code:

```
map(x->x.replaceAll("[^\\p{LD}\\s]",""))
```

Comment: That is not a valid regex.

Comment: I guessed you're using java? If not, please [edit] the tags.

Answer (score 2):

`LD` stands for Letter or Digit so `\p{LD}` means any letter or digit categorized unicode char.
`\s` means any white space char.

You need to escape `\` with  `\`.

`^` is negating both.

Test in java:

```java
System.out.println(".,:;-_#*'´`^° СЕНИШИН ЮРІЙ ВОДИТЕЛЬ abdsf 01152646".replaceAll("[^\\p{LD}\\s]", ""));
```

Comment: This is wrong, `\p{LD}` doesn't exists, see above answer. The property to match digits is `\p{N}` or `\p{Number}`

Comment: @Toto Actually, Cooper is right. In Java `\p{LD}` matches any unicode letters or digits. See [this example](https://www.onlinegdb.com/Sy93noqfv). Alone, `D` is not a valid category but combined with `L`, it matches digits. It seems to be unique to Java though. I haven't been able to find anything explaining the `LD` combination but it just works…

Answer (score 1):

`\p{}` is a syntax used to write unicode regex. See [regular-expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) for more info.

On that page, one can read:

> \p{L} matches a single code point in the category "letter".

So `[^\p{L}\s]` will match anything but a space or a unicode character belonging to the category "letter" (e.g. will match none of the following: `a`, `à` (U+00E0) or `あ` (U+3042)).

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yr5QRk/1)

`LD` is not a valid category and will throw an error.

You can see the engines that support this syntax [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refunicode.html).

Comment: Statement about `LD` is is not correct. It's not documented anywhere that I could find it but it does what Cooper says in their answer.

Answer (score 0):

edit:

The previous regex was  `[^\p{LD}\s]` so it was invalid

For:  `[^\\p{LD}\\s]`

Matches sentence starts with: `\p{LD}\s`

So basic on the edited question, replaces all matches with prefix like: `\p{LD}\s` to empty

Comment: In this case, `\p{}` is a unicode category, with `L` matching letters.

Answer (score 0):

This means any character not includeing in the `[]`:

```
[^\\p{LD}\\s]
```

- `^` - a character that is not including in the `[]`
- `\\` - means `\`
- and every other character: `p` `{` `L` `D` `}` `}`

A match for example:
w,$,y,6, ,(,+...